# Luhn Algorithm not functioning properly c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

As a beginner I have been writing a program to validate a set of credit card numbers using the Luhn algorithm. It partially works however it is not fully correct. If someone could explain to me why I would greatly appreciate it

It should output to the console

```
 Card : 4686006570307405 is valid
 Card : 4686006570307407 is invalid
 Card : 4093650457937474 is invalid
 Card : 4340423439668810 is valid
 Card : 1234567812345670 is valid
 Card : 5509415774265347 is invalid
 Card : X234567812345670 is invalid
 Card : 4539281167952835 is valid
 Card : 4532528637398511 is invalid
 Card : 4653549906803760 is valid
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Instead it outputs

```
 Card : 4686006570307405 is invalid
 Card : 4686006570307407 is invalid
 Card : 4093650457937474 is invalid
 Card : 4340423439668810 is valid
 Card : 1234567812345670 is valid
 Card : 5509415774265347 is invalid
 Card : X234567812345670 is invalid
 Card : 4539281167952835 is invalid
 Card : 4532528637398511 is invalid
 Card : 4653549906803760 is invalid
Press any key to continue . . .
```

My code is as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int convertChartoInt(const char digit)
{
    int numericalDigit = digit - '0';

    if (numericalDigit < 0 || numericalDigit > 9)
    {
        throw(0); //not a numerical digit - throw an exception
    }
    return (numericalDigit);
}

bool validateCardNumber(const string number) {

    bool cardStatus = false;
    int evenCount = 0, oddCount = 0,
        calculatedCheckDigit = 0, checkDigit = 0;
    int reverseNumber[15];

    try {

        checkDigit = convertChartoInt(number.at(15));

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) //Reverse digits
        {
            reverseNumber[14 - i] = convertChartoInt(number.at(i));

            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i = i + 2) //calculate the multiple by 2 of the odd numbers
            {
                int doubledigit = 0;
                doubledigit = 2 * reverseNumber[i];
                if (doubledigit > 9)
                {
                    doubledigit = doubledigit - 9;
                }
                evenCount = evenCount + doubledigit;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < 15; i = i + 2) //calculate the sum of the even numbers
        {
            oddCount = oddCount + reverseNumber[i];
        }
        calculatedCheckDigit = (evenCount + oddCount) % 10; //calculate the check digit
        cardStatus = (calculatedCheckDigit == checkDigit);
    }
    catch (...) {
        cardStatus = false;
    }
    return(cardStatus);
}

int main()
{
    const string testCard[] = { "4686006570307405",
                            "4686006570307407",
                            "4093650457937474",
                            "4340423439668810",
                            "1234567812345670",
                            "5509415774265347",
                            "X234567812345670",
                            "4539281167952835",
                            "4532528637398511",
                            "4653549906803760" };

    int numberOfCards = sizeof(testCard) / sizeof(testCard[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (validateCardNumber(testCard[i]))
        {
            cout << " Card : " << testCard[i].c_str() << " is valid" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << " Card : " << testCard[i].c_str() << " is invalid" << endl;
        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be easier if you explained where in the code is going wrong (you _did_ step through with a debugger, right?) and explained the program piece by piece.

Comment: I think tricky part -- at an early enough level, probably what you said just goes over someone's head ("what's a debugger?"). And once learned, they wouldn't need our help to figure out the problem. But a little more effort invested into this question would be nice.

Comment: Does it give you the same output every time?

Comment: Yes it gives the same output every time... I am quite new to all this so not really familiar with debugging a program. Apologies for taking your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with the algorithm you are trying to implement but it seems the source of your problems is the fact the `reverseNumber` array is not initialized.

In the `validateCardNumber` function, you are setting the `reverseNumber[14 - i]` value and then read `reverseNumber[i]`. For `i = 0` (first iteration of the outermost loop) that means you are reading back some garbage from memory.

Comment: Half correct, one problem is that `reverseNumber` isn't initialized. However, the rest of the problem stems from the implementation of the algorithm. Also, use `- 9` instead of `% 10`.

Comment: Using `- 9` instead of `% 10` wouldn't yield the same result, for any value smaller than 9.

Comment: If `2 * reverseNumber[i]` is `18`, the expected value in `doubledigit` is `9`. It's the sum of both digits, not the modulus. A conditional to check if it is smaller than `9` would be necessary, of course. `reverseNumber[i] > 4 ? (reverseNumber[i] * 2) - 9 : reverseNumber[i] * 2;`

Comment: I see, I didn't know the objective was to sum the digits, forget that then. Thanks for explaining btw

Comment: Thanks simpel01 and @james-root really appreciate the help on this!!